# Get data using Vlookup + count if formulas

Tags: excel

[image: Sheet2[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5udjI.png)

[image: Sheet1]
Hello All
I've attached image of 2 excel sheets. 1st image (sheet1) shows records of Work, City, Emp Name & 2nd image (sheet 2) shows records of Emp Name & Count of work.

As per 2nd Image I'm trying to get count of work done by every emp in 2nd sheet using Vlookup & countif formulas, but it's not providing any value.

So anyone can help with formula?

When executed with Countifs formula it shows in 3rd image.
[image: 3rd image with countifs formula]

Comment: You can use countifs formula

Comment: @NareshBhople I tried , but didn't worked.

Comment: So show what you tried, then we may be able to correct any errors.

Comment: @SolarMike Below is the formula, but it shows count as 1.  =COUNTIFS(A:A,Sheet5!C:C,Sheet5!A:A,"Excel")   Here A column refers to Sheet 6 as per my excel book.

Comment: Have you checked that "excel" is just "excel" and not " excel" or "excel " ? ie spaces make a difference.

Comment: Check your formula ... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Comment: =COUNTIFS(Sheet5!C:C,A2,Sheet5!A:A,"Excel")

Comment: @NareshBhople Thanks for your help. Your given code works, thanks a lot.